# Flutter Web App Source Map not loading in Chrome (http error 404)

Tags: javascript, flutter, dart, google-chrome-devtools, source-maps

I have built a flutter web app using the command:

> flutter build web --release --source-maps

I am running this app on localhost and also on cloud (GCP Cloud Run). In both cases, the web app throws exceptions which are logged in the Chrome Developer Tools console within the file **main.dart.js**. The **main.dart.js** file is a minified/compiled file (low-level & unreadable) and I can't debug the errors logged within in. To debug the errors, I need Chrome to point the location of errors in my source code.

This should be accessible using Source Maps. My web app has source maps enabled and I can see all my source code directories and files in Chrome Devtools > Sources. However, when I click on any **.dart** file within the listed Sources, all I see is:

> Could not load content for http://localhost:3000/lib/main.dart (HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_HTTP_RESPONSE_CODE_FAILURE)

I have the same error (404) in both cloud & localhost builds, for all source code **.dart** files

My minified/compiled Javascript file **main.dart.js** has this source map link attached at the bottom:

> //# sourceMappingURL=main.dart.js.map

I also have *Enable Javascript source maps* setting enabled within Chrome Devtools.

Here's an image of the problem:
[404 error when viewing source maps](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VUf8e.png)

How do I fix this?

Thanks!